# Mac Prolog Console Text with black highlight

Tags: macos, user-interface, console, prolog, swi-prolog

How can I change the colour in the console?  It was working absolutely fine yesterday, but when I run prolog today, the text become black blocks... I tried to change the colour, but it is not giving me any changes...

My application is swi-prolog, and the console is like this at the moment..
[image]

After installing 7.3.11,

[image]

Comment: please download the latest release - 7.3.11 - there was a bug somewhere in the interaction between Qt and El Capitain

Comment: @CapelliC Cheers mate,  but I still got a problem that I can't run the latest version... It keeps saying the developer cannot be confirmed..

Comment: Sorry, cannot help, since I don't have a Mac ready now. I could only report on the mailing list your problem... think you should do, Jan Wielemaker (I guess he is the 'unidentified' developer) is probably interested to know about any problem.

Comment: doesn't the 'Open Anyway' button works ? you can trust the application

Comment: @CapelliC will report :)  for the 'Open Anyway' button, it tries opening the application, but it is just returning the same error message.. "developer unidentified"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the same problem... When I removed the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.swi-prolog.pqConsole.plist that works!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/devel

Download lastest dev version, I was having the same problem, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. In the mean time, try this. This works for me:

- Open the SWI Prolog disk that appears on the desktop.
- Right click the SWI-Prolog icon
- Click show package contents
- Open contents>MacOS>swipl

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this solves the problem. Although they are the same running prolog, I would like to use the gui of the swi-prolog.. :)  However, if I want to run it on terminal, I can download it using `brew download swim-prolog` and run by `swipl`